How does the TeX primitive `\radical"270370` work?
As mentioned, when I was reading TeX by Topic, I came across this passage:

"In the plain format and the Computer Modern math fonts, there is only one radical: the square root construct
\def\sqrt{\radical"270370}
The control sequence \radical is followed by a ⟨24-bit number⟩ which specifies a small and a large variant of the left delimiter as was explained above. Joining the delimiter and the rule is done by letting the delimiter have a large depth, and a height which is equal to the..."

I’m curious about how TeX converts "270370 into the square root symbol. Can someone explain this process?

\radical"270370
should be read as  radical 2 70 3 70 which says the basic sqrt symbol should be taken from fam 2 in position hex 70 then the chain of size-varying sqrt symbols start in the "large op" font in fam 3, starting at position hex 70 (with the details of which glyphs follow for larger sizes is specified in the tfm metrics, and not directly visible from TeX).

I thought maybe it was related to the Reggae song, Roots Radical, by Jimmy Cliff.

In Unicode math, the \sqrt macro is defined as \Uradical fam-num code-num, for example in OpTeX:
\protected\def \sqrt {\Uradical 1 "0221A }

It means that the chain of size-varying sqrt symbols is implemented in the Unicode font at the single code "0221A and we don't need to worry about other codes and other families. The life with Unicode math is much more simpler.
